# highcharts php date and time

Tags: php, highcharts

I am getting some dates and times from a text files with values associated to them:

```
2014-02-03 21:00:02 0350146
2014-02-03 21:30:01 0355156
2014-02-03 22:00:02 0350166
2014-02-03 22:30:02 0350169
...
```

I would like to use highchart to display those values but it is not working. I guess there is a problem with the dates and times coming from the text file and then output by a data.php. This being used by the presentation.php which has some javascript to use the highchart with dates.

I don't know how to make it readable so that javascript will interpret it as dates as I have in the javascript code:

```
Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.value);
```

Thanks for the help,

John.

Comment: Highcharts requires x-values as timestamps, not date or string. See [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes) -  in Axis types part. `Highcharts.dateFormat()` will get timestamp, and return string, so it's not what you need.

Comment: Your Question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767678/highchart-display-json-data-mysql-php?rq=1